# how to apply each index value of an array to each value of a group of selected elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

So if I have an array of 2 values and I want to apply those values to two elements, I can't seem to figure out a way to loop through the selected elements and have a counter or something to represent the index of the array value I want to apply.

Anyone?

For example:

```
myTotal = new Array("7.00", "10.00");

<input class="theTotalInput"></input>
<input class="theTotalInput"></input>
```

So, once I select the inputs,

```
$(".theTotalInput")
```

...

yeah... this is where Im stuck. I cannot find any example documentation that shows applying arrays of values to a bunch of elements in turn - all I have seen is applying the same values to a bunch.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var i = 0;
$(".theTotalInput").each(function() {
    $(this).val(myTotal[i++])
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using this: while I was waiting:

http://docs.jquery.com/Core/eq#position

Which is weird, because I guess I was trying to do it wrong before using this:

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq#index

So mine ended up looking like: 

for(i=0;i<myTotal.length;i++){
$(".theTotalInput").eq(i).val(myTotal[i]);
}

I'm book marking yours, too, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another, possibly shorter way:

```
$(["7.00","10.00"]).each(function(i, val) {
    $(".theTotalInput").eq(i).val(val);
});
```

or:

```
$(".theTotalInput").each(function(i, el){
    $(el).val(myTotal[i]);
});
```